# Angular CLI - Disable compressing SCSS color when building (-apple-pay-button-style)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, applepayjs

I'm integrating Apple Pay in an Angular 10 website. When building the app some SCSS styles colors are converted from `white` to `#fff` or from `black` to `#000`. Normally this is helpful to make the size smaller. In this case, however, it makes Safari fail when styling the button.

Is there any way to tell Angular CLI to not compress a specific SCSS line?

I want this line not to be changed and keep doing what it is doing everywhere else.

`-apple-pay-button-style: white;`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of using `white` have you tried doing `-apple-pay-button-style: #ffffff;`?

Comment: I just tried @rhavelka but it does not work. It's like the Safari expects the word and that is why I'm trying to just disable any optimization for that line.